# Can a single Chainlink HTTP GET return 2 values from the same API?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm currently using Chainlink's example HTTP GET code twice to pull Uniswap price and Uniswap supply from a CoinGecko API (see below). I'd like to pull both price and supply from the API in the same "request" and "fulfill" functions so that I can calculate market cap (market_cap = supply * price) within the "fulfill" function. (I realize I can just pull market cap from the API, but I'd like to calculate it for development reasons.)

Is there a way to change the below code to do this? Does Chainlink allow this?

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/master/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
  
    uint256 public uniPrice;
    uint256 public uniSupply;
    //uint256 public uniMarketCap;
 
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Chainlink - 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e
     * Chainlink - 29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() public {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e;
        jobId = "29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }

//dont forget to fund contract with link

    function requestUniPrice() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfillUniPrice.selector);

        request.add("get", "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=USD&ids=uniswap%2C%20sushi%2C%20pancakeswap-token&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false");
        
        request.add("path","0.current_price");

        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    function requestUniSupply() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfillUniSupply.selector);

        request.add("get", "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=USD&ids=uniswap%2C%20sushi%2C%20pancakeswap-token&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false");
        
        request.add("path","0.circulating_supply");

        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }

    function fulfillUniPrice(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _uniPrice) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        uniPrice = _uniPrice;
    }
    
    function fulfillUniSupply(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _uniSupply) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        uniSupply = _uniSupply;
    }

    function withdrawLink() external {
        LinkTokenInterface linkToken = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(linkToken.transfer(msg.sender, linkToken.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, you have to make multiple requests.

Currently, the EthTX core adapter can only write a single value that is no larger than 32 bytes onto a blockchain. If multiple values are needed, the data will need to be returned by making multiple requests.

Reference: [Chainlink docs FAQ](https://docs.chain.link/docs/faq/#how-can-i-get-multiple-values-with-a-single-request)